# django 1.7.1 - migrate: django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, makemigrations

I have an existing app which has two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
  #...

class B(models.Modele):
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)
  # ..
```

and I had django 1.6, now I upgraded to 1.7.1 and I did:

```
python manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

and it created two migration steps for model A and B in 0001_initial.py. then i did:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

but here i am getting

```
django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError
```

this is the screenshot:

[image]

how can I resolve this? myapp is already in use in production with things in DB, so I need to be careful if it comes to deleting or updating Foreignkeys etc... this is really annoying, i would love to have django 1.7

Comment: i reverted django back to 1.6 for now. i hope, this issue is fixed in 1.8 so i can directly upgrade to 1.8 without this error above